# AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, databricks

can everyone help me with this one?

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf


def sql_writer(db, table_name, df, mode):
  server = 'my-server'
  username = 'username'
  password = 'password'
  schema = 'Reports'
  database = db

  sconf=SparkConf().setAppName("test")
  spark=SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sconf).getOrCreate()

    # Write Spark DataFrame to MSSQL using JDBC
  spark.write \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("user", username) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .mode("append") \
        .save()

  print("DataFrame written to MSSQL successfully!")
```

Howerver, when I try to run this one:

```
sql_writer('DatabaseName',
          'TableName',
          mydf,
          mode=mode
        )
```

Here's what I got:
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'write'

Answer (score 0):

The `.write` method is called on the Dataframe instance, not on the `SparkSession` instance - you need to produce a dataframe first before you can write it.  Replace the `spark` with `df`, and it will be written